# how to make a loop with md5sum test on a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, hashsum

I've this script that creates a mysql dump of a database and sends it to a storage server. But I see that, sometimes, the generated files is of wrong size, even sending the file with rsync.

I'd like to test the remote file for md5sum and if hash is the same, the local file is removed. If the hash is different, though, the rsync is re-attempted.

The original script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# database credentials

DATABASEHOST=<host>
DATABASEUSER=<user>
DATABASEPASSWORD=<password>
DATABASESCHEMA=<schema>
DATABASEENV=<env>

# Local directory of mysqldump file
LOCALDIR=<localdir>

# Temporary directory for compressed file
TEMPDIR=<tempdir>

# Remote Directory for backups.
REMOTEDIR=<remote-dir>

# USERname to login as
BACKUPUSER=<backupuser>

# Backup host to login to
BACKUPHOST=<backuphost>

# mysqldump file
MYSQLDUMPFILE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"_bkp_"$DATABASESCHEMA".sql

# compressed file
COMPRESSEDFILE="$(date +%Y%m%d)"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz

#--- end config


echo $(date +%H:%M)
echo "Creating the MySQL dump" 
mysqldump --host="$DATABASEHOST" --user="$DATABASEUSER" --password="$DATABASEPASSWORD" --single-transaction "$DATABASESCHEMA" > "$LOCALDIR"/"$MYSQLDUMPFILE"

#echo "Generating md5sum"
md5sum "$LOCALDIR"/* > "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk

#echo "Compressing the dump and checklist"
tar -cvzf "$TEMPDIR"/$(date +%Y%m%d)"_"$DATABASEENV"_"$DATABASESCHEMA".tar.gz" "$LOCALDIR"/*

#echo "Sending the compressed file to storage location"
rsync -azvh "$TEMPDIR"/"$COMPRESSEDFILE" "$BACKUPHOST":"$REMOTEDIR"

echo "Removing generated files"
rm "$LOCALDIR"/checklist.chk > /dev/null 2>&1

rm "$LOCALDIR"/"$MYSQLDUMPFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1

rm "$TEMPDIR"/"$COMPRESSEDFILE" > /dev/null 2>&1

echo $(date +%H:%M)
```

Comment: Have you checked the exit status of `rsync`? (`$?`) It *should* be non-zero if it fails. You can use `if` to test for zero/non-zero: `if ! rsync «rsync-args» ; then echo "rsync failed"; fi`, or of course use `if [ $? -ne 0 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- rsync knows when a file is incomplete.
  Just run rsync regularly, and it will by itself take care to re-send new parts of the file as needed.
- It could happen that $TEMPDIR is too small to contain the tar czvf ? then you would send that (incomplete) file with rsync?
- why not simplify:

  - dump the DB as you did
  - then `cd "$LOCALDIR" && rsync -azvh *_bkp_*.sql "$BACKUPHOST":"$REMOTEDIR"`

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing should never happen without rsync indicating an error or your machine crashing (and thus rsync never returning, because the machine died). See [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/359957/how-to-make-a-loop-with-md5sum-test-on-a-bash-script/359971#comment637335_359957) for some suggestions about that.

However, computing and storing a checksum is good practice, and checking is fairly easy—as long as you can ssh to the other machine or have a separate script run on it (presuming none of the file names have single-quotes in them):

```shell
# the cut below is to get the MD5 only, without the file name.
md5_local="$(md5sum "$REMOTEDIR/$COMPRESSEDFILE" | cut -d' ' -f1)"
md5_remote="$(ssh "$BACKUPHOST" "md5sum '$REMOTEDIR/$COMPRESSEDFILE'" | cut -d' ' -f1)"
if [ "$md5_local" = "" ]; then
    echo "Something went terribly wrong."
elif [ "$md5_local" = "$md5_remote" ]; then
    echo "MD5s match"
else
    echo "MD5s DO NOT match"
fi
```

Another thing you could do—and is probably preferable—is to add the MD5 file to your rsync, and the store it with the backup. This lets you confirm the backup hasn't bit-rotted.

PS: You should consider a real backup system, at least if you have multiple machines.